# how can I restrict the number of characters in XLForm?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xlform

I use [row.cellConfigAtConfigure setObject:@(5) forKey:XLFormTextViewMaxNumberOfCharacters] invaild

```
row = [XLFormRowDescriptor formRowDescriptorWithTag:kHouseTitle rowType:XLFormRowDescriptorTypeTextView title:@"HouseTitle"];
row.value = self.houseInfo.title;
[row.cellConfigAtConfigure setObject:@(5) forKey:XLFormTextViewMaxNumberOfCharacters];
[section addFormRow:row];
```

because I need different lengths for rows. now I find a way to dealing it.

```
-(UITextField *)getCurrentTextFiledWithRow:(XLFormRowDescriptor *)row {
XLFormBaseCell *cell = [row cellForFormController:self];
if ([cell isKindOfClass:[XLFormTextFieldCell class]]) {
    XLFormTextFieldCell *xlFormTextFieldCell = (XLFormTextFieldCell *)cell;
    return xlFormTextFieldCell.textField;
}
else {
    return nil;
}
```

}

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
XLFormRowDescriptor *buildingAreaRow = [self.form formRowWithTag:kBuildingArea];
XLFormRowDescriptor *livingAreaRow = [self.form formRowWithTag:kLivingArea];
XLFormRowDescriptor *housePriceRow = [self.form formRowWithTag:kHouseCellingPrice];
NSString *newString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];

if ([self getCurrentTextFiledWithRow:buildingAreaRow] == textField) {
    if(newString.length > 4){
        return NO;
    }
}
else if ([self getCurrentTextFiledWithRow:livingAreaRow] == textField) {
   // TODO
}
else if([self getCurrentTextFiledWithRow:housePriceRow] == textField) {
   //TODO
}
return YES;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

you can use in this way, I guess

```
NSString *const XLFormTextViewMaxNumberOfCharacters = @"textViewMaxNumberOfCharacters";

 - (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text 
{
 if (self.textViewMaxNumberOfCharacters) 
  {
    // Check maximum length requirement
    NSString *newText = [textView.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:text];
    if (newText.length > self.textViewMaxNumberOfCharacters.integerValue) {
        return NO;
    }
 }

//perform based on your need
  return [self.formViewController textView:textView shouldChangeTextInRange:range replacementText:text];
  }
```